# Google api ruby client failing

Tags: ruby, api, calendar, client

I'm having trouble using the Google API Client on a ruby project.

I'm following the code example provided by google.
The README is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/calendar/README.md?repo=samples).
The source code you personalize is [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/calendar/calendar.rb?repo=samples).

It lays the foundations for a basic sinatra app which redirects you to Google where you can sign in and authorize the app to see your calendar information.

After that it directs you back to your app where I am met with the following error:
`undefined method 'bytesize' for #<Faraday::Response:0x007f98f5beb668>`

The trace hops from sinatra to thin to rack and back to sinatra - nothing really useful in there. I know the last code to be called from the app is:

`result = @client.execute(:api_method => @calendar.events.list, :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'primary'})`

I've seen some other stackoverflow posts similar to this but in those cases people are always defining their Faraday parameters themselves. Is this an issue with the Google API or does anyone have any suggestions where I might be doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those hitting the same problem: I have not found a solution. I have however successfully connected an app to the Google API and can access all the info and methods I want.

Decided to go about this with `omniauth`. It's really simple, there's a [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) on how omniauth works, and a great walk through of using omniauth to connect to Google [here](http://gregandrachel.baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails). It describes specifically the act of connecting to the Google Calendar, but all you would need to do is change the `client.discovered_api` setter and the `client.execute` call in the sessions_controller to which ever you want. Decent documentation and code examples at developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Best of luck.